# Are the different mythological series by Rick Riordan set in the same universe?

Tags: rick-riordan, intertextuality

Rick Riordan is the author of many series of fictional works about mythology. These include: *Percy Jackson & the Olympians*, *The Heroes of Olympus*, *The Kane Chronicles*, the book set *Demigods and Magicians*, *Magnus Chase and the Gods of Asgard*, and *The Trials of Apollo*.

However, he is not solely retelling the classic myths, but also adding new events. This leads me to wonder whether those new events have occurred in his other mythological series. If they do occur in the same universe, how has that been shown in the text and where can that be seen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes.

The *Percy Jackson and the Olympians*, *The Heroes of Olympus*, and *The Trials of Apollo* are definitely in the same universe – they center on Camp Half-Blood.

In *The Kane Chronicles*, we can conclude that they *are* in the same universe, given that there are no less than *three* crossover stories with PJO - *The Son of Sobek*, *The Staff of Serapis*, and *The Crown of Ptolemy* - combined with these quotes:

> ”So you can’t live in Manhattan?” she asked.
> Amos’s brow furrowed as he looked across at the Empire State Building. “Manhattan has other problems. Other gods. It’s best we stay separate.”
> -*The Red Pyramid*, chapter 5

…

> And sometimes when I looked across the water, I could swear I was seeing things. Sadie laughed about it, but once I thought I saw a flying horse.
> --*The Throne of Fire*, chapter 6

Combined with the fact that Drew Tanaka and Lacy from *The Lost Hero* make an appearance in *The Serpent’s Shadow*, we can conclude that *The Kane Chronicles* is set it the same universe.

And now for *Magnus Chase and the Gods of Asgard*.

This one is a fairly easy **yes**, given that Magnus is Annabeth’s cousin, and that Annabeth, Frederick, and Percy Jackson<sup>1</sup> appear in *Magnus Chase*, and that Apollo’s fall was mentioned to Magnus, and that Annabeth keeps disappearing in *The Trials of Apollo* for ‘family reasons’.

---

<sup>1</sup>As evidenced by the fact that at the end of *The Hammer of Thor* Annabeth says that ‘I think it’s time for you to meet Percy Jackson’.

---

As an aside, the [Riordan Wiki](http://riordan.wikia.com/wiki/Riordan_Wiki), which I frequently visit/edit, has a [list of all series interactions](http://riordan.wikia.com/wiki/Series_Interactions) that's worth taking a peek at.